ADO Pipeline Task Warning (Node is end-of-life)
I have an ADO Pipeline (yaml) that suddenly started to get warnings related to in-the-box tasks. Here is the example of the warning:
##[warning]Task 'Deploy Databricks Notebooks' version 0 (deploynotebooks@0) is dependent on a Node version (6) that is end-of-life. Contact the extension owner for an updated version of the task. Task maintainers should review Node upgrade guidance: https://aka.ms/node-runner-guidance
Downloading task: startcluster (0.5.6)
Task Warnings in ADO Pipeline
Researching documentation I did not find any updated versions if these tasks. I have also tried loading Node libraries and also changing the Node to a different version - it did not solve the issue, saying that 'RunnerAlreadyInstalled'.
Has anyone encountered similar issues with end-of-life nodes?

I can get the same warning when using the Deploy Databricks Notebooks task(Task version 0.5.6) from extension: DevOps for Azure Databricks in Azure DevOps.

It indicates that the pipeline task is using the end-of-life node version(node 6). The warning is from the extension task itself. We are not able to update it in Pipeline.
Usually we need to contact the Extension developer to update the node version that the extension depends on from source code.
However, this extension is currently in an unpublished state. This means that the extension has been archived and will not be updated any more.
Based on my test, this warning does not affect the use of the task for the time being. You can ignore this warning and continue to use it.
On the other hand, I found another extension: Databricks Script Deployment Task by Data Thirst that can deploy Azure Databricks tasks. But its source repo has also been archived. It will also encounter the same warning later.
In the future, I suggest that you can consider gradually changing to using custom scripts for Azure Databricks deployments. For more detailed info, you can refer to this doc: Continuous integration and delivery on Azure Databricks using Azure DevOps
